# Finding the maximum and minimum value a number can take in a set whose mean and rms is constrained

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I'm a freshman in college with no prior experience in non linear optimization. This is a question I encountered in an MCQ format.

**Problem**

$\ x_i \epsilon Z $

$\ i = {1,2,3,4,5} $

$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i = 10$

$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^2 = 40$

Find the maximum and minimum value that $\ x_i $  can take.

**Attempt**

I replaced $x_i$ with $k_i + m$ and found

$\ M = \sum_{i=1}^5 k_i = 10-5m$

$\ P = \sum_{i=1}^5 k_i^2 = 40 + 5m^2 - 20m$

Solving $M^2=P$ yielded $m = 1,3$ which generated the solution set

{1,1,1,1,6}

{3,3,3,3,-2}

indicating that 6 and -2 were the required values, however I'm clueless as to why the math worked out in this manner.

**Queries**

I'd like to know why $M^2=P$ yielded the critical condition, how many solution sets there are to this problem, as well as a general approach to such questions.

---

This is my first post on this forum, thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome, @Glaxionaizer!

Comment: I got $-2$ to $6$ too by running it through a basic python script but where did you get the idea to set $M^2=P$? Is that what you were taught in class? I don't understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

**An Interpretation**

If you applied the technique of Lagrange multipliers, then you would know that, at an optimal point $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\right)=\left(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5\right)$, it must hold that $y_1=y_2=y_3=y_4$.  Then, you can set $m$ to be the common value of $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$.  Write $y_5=m+t$.  Then, you have
$$t=\sum_{i=1}^5\,\left(y_i-m\right)=\sum_{i=1}^5\,y_i -5m=10-5m$$
and
$$t^2=\sum_{i=1}^5\,\left(y_i-m\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^5\,y_i^2-2m\,\sum_{i=1}^5\,y_i+5m^2=40-20m+5m^2\,.$$
Therefore, 
$$40-20m+5m^2=t^2=(10-5m)^2\,.$$